# How to find current elements root div class?

Tags: jquery

When clicked on a checkbox , i am trying to find the root div class of that element

I was trying with different options ,but for all of them i am getting undefined .

```
$(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function(e) {
    var cls = $(this).find('div:first').attr('class') ;
    alert(cls)

});
```

When clicked on activateUiHTML checkbox, i wanted to display **activateUiHTMLparentdivclass**

When clicked on ordersdiv checkbox , i wanted to display **parentsordersdivclass**

http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/31/

could anybody please tell me how to do this .

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `.parents().last()` to find the last parent element, I think you have some confusion with what is a root element is.

```
$(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function(e) {
    var cls = $(this).parents('div').last().attr('class') ;
    alert(cls);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/32/)

Comment: "root" refers to ancestor or parent elements; "child" or "leaf" refers to descendants.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
var cls = $(this).find('div:first').attr('class') ;
```

to

```
var cls = $(this).closest('div').attr('class') ;
```

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/34/)**